# sub-user join with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, join, sqlalchemy

I am trying to find a good solution for the following problem

- There are main-users and sub-users which identify themselves via a parent_user_id.
- All users also get additional information from the company table

I need to join sub-users to the main-users to get the company information, as well as doing the same for main-users

Users (contains sub and main users)

- user_id
- login
- parent_user_id
- company_id

Company (contains company information for all users of this company)

- company_id
- contact_address

when I search for the user with id 7, it should return the login and the contact address of this user. This is relatively easy because I simply join from Users to Company directly.
However, this user 7 can also have a sub-user, which has user_id 11 and parent_user_id 7.

I first need to join from the parent_user_id 7 to the user 7, and then join from that user's company_id to the Company table to get the contact address.

The challenge here is that a main-user will have a parent_user_id of "NULL", therefore it cannot join from it's parent_user_id to its own user_id. This only works for sub-users.

What I did is a join( or_( ) ) for both parent's company_id as well as the user's company_id (after joining all the users to their parents).

Is this the most common solution for this problem? it seems a bit lengthy, requires aliases, outer joins and an or_ join to allow the two different types of users

```
user = Users.alias("user")
parent = Users.alias("parent")
company = Company.alias("company")

joined = user.join(parent, user.c.parent_user_id == parent.c.id, isouter=True)
joined = joined.join(company, or_(user.c.company_id == company.c.company_id, parent.c.company_id == company.c.company_id)

sql = select(user.c.id, user.c.login, company.c.contact_address).select_from(joined)
```

Maybe there is a "pattern" for this sort of problem?
I have looked at reverse cte, but I'm not even sure if it applies to this case. There are only sub-users and no deeper nesting (and no "levels" of depth). Main-users simply have no parent_user_id

Edit:
Ideally, I am looking for an SQLAlchemy core answer that doesnt use classes, therefore it only uses the metadata from the database using autoload

Comment: How many levels of user--subuser are possible? Only one?

Comment: yep, only one. Main-users and sub-users, no further nesting

Comment: I think it is a good solution. I would only replace last `joined = ` with `joined = joined.join(company, company.c.company_id == func.coalesce(user.c.company_id, parent.c.company_id))` with the reason that I find `OR` often slow and difficult to optimize, although it is semantically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As commented, you solution is good enough, I think*.

However, I usually try to "hide" implementation details for such tricky situations by encapsulating them into the responsible data class itself. In this case I would add a [Hybrid Attribute](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) to the `User` class like so:

```py
class User(...):
   ...

    # relationships
    parent_user = relationship("User", remote_side=[user_id], backref="subusers")
    company = relationship(Company, backref="users")

    @hybrid_property
    def company_contact_address(self):
        company = self.company or self.parent_user.company
        return company.contact_address

    @company_contact_address.expression
    def company_contact_address(cls):
        PU = aliased(User)
        user_id = case((cls.company_id.is_(None), cls.parent_user_id), else_=cls.user_id)  # sqlite, universal?
        return (
            select(Company.contact_address.label("contact_address"))
            .join(PU, and_(Company.company_id == PU.company_id, PU.user_id==user_id))
            .scalar_subquery()
        )
```

in which case the usage becomes very clear:

```
query = select(User.user_id, User.login, User.company_contact_address)
for _row in session.execute(query):
    print(_row)
```

Comment: Interesting! However, I dont have a User class, this is simply the Table itself using `sqlalchemy.Table("user", metadata, autoload=True)` in my code so I dont think I can use this. Thanks for your answer and comment, I will probably still accept this.

Comment: actually, can you explain the line with case()? In case the company_id is None, it should use the parent's company_id, and this will define the user_id for the join? How does this work? Shouldn't this be checking the user's parent_user_id instead?

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. The `user_id = ...` is to find the user_id from which the `contact_address` should be taken. the `CASE` in here is just a `IF` statement, but it works well for multiple RDBMS. When we understand which user_id to use, we join on the `Company` table accordingly. _This is just another way of finding the right `Company` row_

Comment: Well, if you do not use mapped classes, then this is not a solution for you.